# Python MySQL запрос с подстановкой значений

Tags: mysql, python, flask

Пытаюсь создать во Flask sql запрос с подстановкой параметра. Такой код выдает ошибку:

> ```
> raise LookupError('the converter %r does not exist' % converter_name)
> ```
>
> `LookupError`: the converter 'str' does not exist.

Эта ошибка не гуглится :)

```
@app.route("/test/<str:y>")
def itemCount(y):
    resp1 = ''
    h=0
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='***', user='****', passwd='****', db='****', charset='utf8')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT `ProductModelPrice`,`productBrand`,`productModelNumber`,`productModelName`,`productCategory`,`img`, `akciya` FROM `images` WHERE `productCategory` = %s ''', y)
```

При этом в другом моем скрипте строка:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO `images` (`productModelPrice`, `productBrand`, `productModelNumber`, `productCategory`, `productModelName`,`img`, `tag`, `akciya`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(price,brand,mNumber,category, mName,img1,tag,akciya)).
```

Работает отлично. Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `y` на `(y,)`

Comment: Ошибка гуглится и приводит к этому [тикету](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/537). Посмотрите, может он окажется полезным. Какая версия Python? Вы уверены, что этот обработчик действительно выполняется? В тикете предлагается заменить `str` на `string` при определении роута

Comment: Пожалуйста приложите полный traceback

Comment: @soon, спасибо ваше решение помогло